# get shared library soname in a Python program

Tags: python, version, shared-libraries, elf, objdump

I'm writing a Python wrapper for a shared Linux library using ctypes. Is there some way to extract the library's soname programmatically (e.g., possibly via some library for accessing its ELF data)? (I know that I can obtain this information from the output of the objdump command, but I was curious whether it can be done without having to execute a system command.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out; solution (using pyelftools) posted [here](https://gist.github.com/lebedov/5111696).

Answer (score 4):

Of course, you may execute `objdump` using `subprocess` and then parse its output to get soname, but that is what you want to avoid. However, a shell example is [here](http://oopsinc.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/get-soname-from-library/).

There also is [pyelftools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyelftools/) to look at. As far as I see from the docs, it should be able to retrieve all the necessary data.